# thymeleaf caching with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I have found many, many posts about disabling template caching with Thymeleaf for development, but I can't get it to work.  My stack:

- Spring Boot 1.5.7
- spring-boot-devtools
- Thymeleaf
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.2

I don't need to auto-rebuild: I've mapped the "rebuild" command in IntelliJ to ⌘-S and this works great for hot-swapping Java classes. However, css and html templates still only show changes if I restart my server.

My application.properties:

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/templates/  
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

I've tried:
• moving the templates folder into webapp/resources (and adjusting the templates root)
• wiring up different kinds of template resolvers (e.g. FileTemplateResolver)
• configuring the template resolver in a `@Configuration` file instead of letting Spring Boot use defaults and `application.properties` values

Here are the relevant entries in my pom.xml file:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>  

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: After editing your template please also MAKE the project using `CTRL+F9`.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan thanks for the quick response: actually, that's the command I mapped to ⌘-S on my Mac (in my original post I inaccurately call it "rebuild"), and it has no effect... still need to restart server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, it is specific to IntelliJ:

I was using a "Tomcat" template under Launch Configurations.  Once I changed it to a "Spring Boot" configuration template, it behaves as expected.

Comment: I have the same issues you mentioned, but I don't know what you mean in your answer. I know where to change the run configuration in general, but I don't know where/how to change it from _Tomcat_ to _Spring Boot_ template. Neither of them is listed under _Templates_. Any hints?

Comment: Nevermind. I found [this guide](http://blog.gtiwari333.com/2019/04/spring-boot-how-to-skip-cache.html), which worked fine for me. :)